# I can't see the comments on my Blogger posts

Tags: security, blogger, comments

When checking my Blogger account I can see that there are some comments on the posts. Most have just one comment - which I'm sure are the "ping back" comment from me sharing the post on Google+.

However, one has 3 comments, but I'm unable to see them.

[image: My Blogger Dashboard]

The "3" (1) is underlined and the cursor changes to a hand when I hover over it. However, clicking does nothing.

I also noticed that when I click the "3" a shield icon (2) appears in the address bar. Clicking that shows a little dialog that states:

> This page includes script from unauthorised sources.

- Is it safe to load this script?
- Is there any way I can view this script?

I would like to think that the script is from Google, but just on a http connection rather than https, but I'm in a suspicious mood today. Even after loading the "unsafe" script I still can't see the comments.

Ultimately I just want to review the comments on my blog.

Comment: that looks like your browser blocking mixed mode content

Comment: @Sathya - Yeah - well that's the default.

Comment: What happens when you view the post, do any of the comments show underneath it?

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ - Nope. The comments don't show.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because I have Google+ comments turned on - https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2981015?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your blog and I see it uses Blogger Dynamic Templates. Firstly, to solve the problem with the comments not showing under the post.

Your blog doesn't have a commonly used fix in the template (its absence has known to cause issues with sidebar not appearing, comment form not appearing, custom CSS not applying). I suggest you do the following changes in your template.

Before you proceed, please backup your template by going to *Template* → *Backup/Restore* → *Download Full Template*, so that you can switch back to it if anything goes wrong while editing.

Once you have a backup of your blog template, go to *Template* → *Edit HTML* and you will see the editor come up. Scroll down to the bottom of your template, to where you see code that looks like this:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
    }, 0);
</script>
```

Change the 0 to **500** so it looks like this:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
    }, 500);
</script>
```

Click on **Save Template**. And now check your blog; you should be able to see the comments.

About not being able to see the comments in the Blogger dashboard, that’s because Google+ comments aren't fully integrated with Blogger dashboard currently. Another way to check the comments you have received is by going to Google+ and searching your blog post URL (search the blogspot.com version not the ccTLD ones).

Also, Blogger is now rolling out a new feature which sends a Google+ notification when anybody comments on your post (see screenshot).

[image: Google+ Notification]